# input text box is hidden behind the keyboard on android browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, keyboard

input text box is hidden behind the keyboard on Android browsers, This issue can be solved by set position fixed for inputs but this's not a professional solution and it's causing many of other problems.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is probably a change to your UI. Most implementations will contain a scrollable div/section

```
.container {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

for when the content expands over the container. This allows the user to continue scrolling without closing the keyboard. Hope this helps!

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your manifest

```
<activity
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
 </activity>
```